# C#: Add data to an SQLMetal generated database class?

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

I used SQLMetal to generate a code file representing my database, and i can't figure out how to add entries to the database from the SQLMetal generated classes. How do i do this? do i just add to the various properties or something?

Comment: It is pretty vague whether you mean "add rows" vs "add properties"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good overview of linq-to-sql, which includes how to add to your database via the auto-generated classes (from SQL Metal). [**Link**](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoSQL5MinuteOverview.ashx)

Essentially:

1. Create your database context object
2. Create a new object (which was auto-generated)
3. Populate your object's properties
4. Add your object to the correct collection within your database context
5. Submit changes to your database context. Voila!

Answer (score 1):

The generated classes are *partial* classes, so you can extend them anywhere else in your assembly with another partial class definition (note: I don't mean extension methods, just another partial class declaration).

That way, you can also re-generate those classes without worrying of overwriting your other extensions of the classes.